# Creating space in program

Tags: python

I have a program that returns this when I run it:

```
A
AAA  
AAAAA
AAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAA
```

however I want it to look like this

```
    A
   AAA  
  AAAAA
 AAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAA
```

My code looks like this:

```
#A triangle
def print_triangle(letters, rows):

    for i in range(rows):

        print(5 * (-i) * "  " + letters * (i * 2 + 1))

print_triangle("A",5)
```

Any advice how to get this "pyramid effect"?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Currently your `for` and `print` statements are at the same indentation level.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you expect `'z'*(-2)` (for example) to produce?

Comment: Originally when I was trying to get this to work I was in the middle of a test so I was trying anything and everything, thats why the code is so terrible haha.

Comment: Protip: Open the python interactive console and *play around* with every little piece you're not sure of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `5 * (-i) * "  "`?
Try this:

```
def print_triangle(letters, rows):
    for i in range(rows):
        print((rows-i-1) * " " + letters * (i * 2 + 1))
print_triangle("A",5)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `str.format` for best effect.

```
BASE_WIDTH = 7
formattingstring = "{}{}{}".format("{:^",BASE_WIDTH,"}")
for substring in ['A',"AAA","AAAAA","AAAAAAA"]:
    formattingstring.format(substring)
```

This uses some formatting trickery to create a string `"{:^7}"` that uses the constant `BASE_WIDTH` to pull its size (in this case `7`).

`str.format` replaces all the `{}`s in the original string with the parameters you pass it, and anything after the `:` is a formatting string. In this case, the `^` means to center align, and the `7` means to have a width of 7 characters.

Comment: The would be improved by setting `BASE_WIDTH = 2*rows-1` and using `[formattingstring.format("A"*(n*2+1)) for n in range(rows)]`